# AngularJS model update but view not updating

Tags: angularjs, angular-carousel

If I update model from input field the view also update properly.

here's the code

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="number" ng-model="optionsOfDirective.startSlide"class="form-control">
  </div>
```

and the model is

```
        $scope.optionsOfDirective = {
                startSlide: 0
            };
```

and the picture 
 [image]
 But if I update the model data on mouse click through controller the model value got updated and the view also but after a second the view return to it's previous stage.[image]

Here's the ng-click code

```
<div>
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button" data-slide="next"
 ng-click="btnClickCounter();" ng-model="optionsOfDirective.startSlide">      Next </a>
```

And the model update

```
$scope.btnClickCounter = function () {
  $scope.optionsOfDirective.startSlide=7;
};
```

Why the view is not remaining same if i set value in controller.

Comment: Post a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do change it somewhere, do you know how to sue Batarang - the chrome extension for angular debugging?

Comment: Remove the `ng-model` from `a` tag

Comment: @JBNizet ok i am posting the plunkr.